# Recursive logic for parsing string into complex boolean?

Tags: ruby, parsing, filtering, boolean-logic, sequel

I'm sure this has been done before, I just can't find it.

I need to turn something like, "((A OR B) AND C) OR D" into a database query for an attribute.  Specifically I'm using Ruby Sequel.  Can anyone point me at an example or utility or something that will keep me from reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Have a look at treetop: http://treetop.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Thanks fellas.  I was basically looking for code / pseudocode that already did what I was talking about.  We're only talking about three operators here, right?  I'm sure its out there somewhere as this doesn't seem to be a terribly unusual thing to do.  Anyway, we are in a hurry so we just bailed on parentheses for now (current customers can do without).  Handling just AND and OR is no problem in a single pass.  We'll revisit this later and implement parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a grammar using [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) and automatically generate a Ruby parser for those type of strings. ANTLR is a parser generator and it allows you to define a grammar for a language (such as a the boolean language that you described).

After parsing, you can specify what actions need to be taken to build the desired data structure (in your case a tree data structure that captures the structure of the query).

This is not particularly a Ruby problem as ANTLR can also generate parsers for other languages. In your case it would produce a Ruby parser that you can integrate into your application to parse the strings and to produce the data structure that you need.