# How to convert a statement in a string into a format that can be evaluated (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, string, eval

I am writing a quiz program where I need to store boolean statements as strings in an array and output them to the terminal as part of a question. I then want to evaluate the contents of these strings and return the value so that I can test whether I answered the question correctly. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
questions = ["!true", "!false", "true || true", "true && false"...]
puts "Answer true or false"
puts questions[0]
answer = gets.chomp
# evaluate value of questions[0] and compare to answer
...
```

Storing just the statements doesn't work the way I need it to:

```
questions = [!true, !false, true || true, true && false...]
puts questions[3].to_s
```

It returns the evaluated statement, ie `"false"`, not `"true && false"`. Any ideas of how to approach this?

Comment: I don't think there is a built in way, but check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119970/string-true-and-false-to-boolean

Comment: I think without eval it hard to implement. You can write some parsing algorithm.

Comment: this can help to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12167613/recursive-logic-for-parsing-string-into-complex-boolean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [eval](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval). Here:

```
a = "true && false"
eval a
# => false

a = "true && true"
eval a
# => true
```

`eval` will let you *"convert a boolean statement stored in a string into a format that can be evaluated"*. You will need to change your logic accordingly to use it.

Comment: Embarrassingly simple! Thanks, this was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Standard disclaimer: This can do way more than just evaluate booleans. It can evaluate *any* Ruby statement (including `exec 'rm -rf /'`). Exercise caution accordingly. (E.g. User input should definitely not passed into this function.)